# Why do links in system PCP welcome emails fail?

Tags: civimail, civicontribute, pcp

I am using 4.6.3 on D7. I have set up PCP campaign associated with a contribution page. Contribution page is active (no end date). The user creates a page successfully, but they do not create a password in process of creating the PCP, even though the profile I am using in the PCP tab requires a user login.

So, they can't log back in after successfully creating the page.

When the user gets their system-generated PCP Welcome email, they are provided links to "login to your account" and "Click this link and follow the prompts". These fail (get page not available message in Chrome).

I looked at the system template for the email. Looks good.

Any thoughts about the problem would be helpful! Thanks!

Comment: I've seen this happen where the links are generated are relative links instead of absolute - e.g. "/civicrm/pcp/etc?variable=1" instead of "http://www.mysite.org/civicrm/pcp/etc?variable=1".  Could you please view the source of your email to see if that applies here?  Also, are you running any sort of CiviCRM multi-site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may have two different issues here.  I left a comment for one.

As for the lack of account signup - go to www.yoursite.org/admin/config/people/accounts (or, if you have standard Drupal menus, *Configuration menu > People > Account Settings*.  Under Registration and cancellation, Who can register accounts - ensure that the value is set to "Visitors" or "Visitors, but administrator approval is required".  If it's set to "Administrators Only", the account signup won't appear on the profile.

Comment: Yes. That was it. Thank you. Visitors can now create accounts and PCPs!

Comment: Jon, in response to the other issue (above) about relative vs. absolute path in the links,YES, I still have that problem. I am able to replace the token {$loginURL} with the static address to the user sign-in, but is there another way to fix this so that the token produces the absolute path in the system generated messages to PCP users?

Comment: BTW: I am not using any multi-site installation.

Comment: John - I hadn't heard of folks experiencing this without multi-site, I always assumed it was related to multi-site.  I've spent a lot of time trying to troubleshoot it, with no luck.

Comment: Thanks, Jon! The workaround will have to suffice. Not sure if the templates are overwritten in upgrades--probably not. I'll just live with it.